# Placing Google Street View and Google Maps with marker point side by side

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to place Street View window based on marker point from Google Maps side by side. Here is the code I need help with:

```
 <div id="property_map"></div>
            <script>
                /* Property Detail Page - Google Map for Property Location */

                function initialize_property_map(){

                    var propertyMarkerInfo = <?php echo json_encode( $property_marker ); ?>

                    var url = propertyMarkerInfo.icon;
                    var size = new google.maps.Size( 42, 57 );

                    // retina
                    if( window.devicePixelRatio > 1.5 ) {
                        if ( propertyMarkerInfo.retinaIcon ) {
                            url = propertyMarkerInfo.retinaIcon;
                            size = new google.maps.Size( 83, 113 );
                        }
                    }

                    var image = {
                        url: url,
                        size: size,
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size( 42, 57 ),
                        origin: new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point( 21, 56 )
                    };

                    var propertyLocation = new google.maps.LatLng( propertyMarkerInfo.lat, propertyMarkerInfo.lang );
                    var propertyMapOptions = {
                        center: propertyLocation,
                        zoom: 15,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        scrollwheel: false
                    };
                    var propertyMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("property_map"), propertyMapOptions);
                    var propertyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: propertyLocation,
                        map: propertyMap,
                        icon: image
                    });
                }

                window.onload = initialize_property_map();
            </script>
```

On developers.google.com I found this code for displaying Google Maps and Street View side by side and that's something I want to achieve, but I need this to be dynamic and updates whenever I move the marker point.

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="pano"></div>
<script>

  function initialize() {
    var fenway = {lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: fenway,
      zoom: 14
    });
    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('pano'), {
          position: fenway,
          pov: {
            heading: 34,
            pitch: 10
          }
        });
    map.setStreetView(panorama);
  }
</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initialize">
</script>
```

I tried to copy/paste piece of code responsible for Street View Panorama, but with no success.I would appreciate any help with this.

**UPDATE:**
I tried to combine these two codes in one and the result was that the Google Maps freezes(cant be dragged over with mouse) and the marker was gone as well, Street View window was blank as well. This is the code I tried:

```
<div id="property_map"></div>
            <div id="pano" style="float:left; height:100%; width:45%"></div>
            <script>
                /* Property Detail Page - Google Map for Property Location */

                function initialize_property_map(){

                    var propertyMarkerInfo = <?php echo json_encode( $property_marker ); ?>

                    var url = propertyMarkerInfo.icon;
                    var size = new google.maps.Size( 42, 57 );

                    // retina
                    if( window.devicePixelRatio > 1.5 ) {
                        if ( propertyMarkerInfo.retinaIcon ) {
                            url = propertyMarkerInfo.retinaIcon;
                            size = new google.maps.Size( 83, 113 );
                        }
                    }

                    var image = {
                        url: url,
                        size: size,
                        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size( 42, 57 ),
                        origin: new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point( 21, 56 )
                    };

                    var propertyLocation = new google.maps.LatLng( propertyMarkerInfo.lat, propertyMarkerInfo.lang );
                    var propertyMapOptions = {
                        center: propertyLocation,
                        zoom: 15,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        scrollwheel: false
                    };
                    var propertyMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("property_map"), propertyMapOptions);
                    var propertyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: propertyLocation,
                        map: propertyMap,
                        icon: image
                    });
                    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
                        document.getElementById('pano'), {
                        position: propertyLocation,
                        pov: {
                        heading: 34,
                        pitch: 10
                        }
                        });
                       map.setStreetView(panorama);

                }

                window.onload = initialize_property_map();
            </script>
            <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=IremovedmyAPI&callback=initialize">
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** Looks like the problem is that I have two function calls and I need help to turn this into one call.

Comment: Why do you think the streetview code you posted doesn't work?  It works for me (with the appropriate CSS).  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue you are trying to fix.

Comment: @geocodezip I didnt say that the streetview code doesn't work. This code works as a standalone solution. What I wanted to say is I need to tweak the first code by adding streetview image to the function initialize_property_map() in the way that it outputs both google map and streetview image next to it with the marker of the property location. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: @geocodezip I updated my post with the code I tried to run.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.  What is `propertyMarkerInfo`? Second request: please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip I placed the code in the update and the issue is that the streetview map doesnt show up on the front end. propertyMarkerInfo is a variable that holds the location for the marker on the map, latitude and longtitude I guess. When I try to run this code I got two error messages on the console: ReferenceError: map is not defined
 and
InvalidValueError: initialize is not a function

Comment: Please provide a test value for `propertyMarkerInfo` that you **know** shows the issue (so your question contains a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: @geocodezip I don't think I understand what you're trying to achieve here. Could you be more specific and use the words that not only professional coders understand but also someone who is trying to learn something here? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114169/discussion-between-radi-and-geocodezip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your onload function definition.

```
window.onload = initialize_property_map();
```

Should be

```
window.onload = initialize_property_map;
```

The `()` after the function causes it to be executed immediately and the returned value used as the function to execute "onload" which is null since the function doesn't return anything.

(and `map.setStreetView(panorama);` should be `propertyMap.setStreetView(panorama);`)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize_property_map() {

  var propertyMarkerInfo = {
    lat: 42.345573,
    lang: -71.098326,
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
  };

  var url = propertyMarkerInfo.icon;
  var size = new google.maps.Size(42, 57);

  var image = {
    url: url,
    size: size,
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(42, 57),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 56)
  };

  var propertyLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(propertyMarkerInfo.lat, propertyMarkerInfo.lang);
  var propertyMapOptions = {
    center: propertyLocation,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false
  };
  var propertyMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("property_map"), propertyMapOptions);
  var propertyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: propertyLocation,
    map: propertyMap,
    icon: image
  });
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('pano'), {
      position: propertyLocation,
      pov: {
        heading: 34,
        pitch: 10
      }
    });
  propertyMap.setStreetView(panorama);

}

window.onload = initialize_property_map;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#property_map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#pano {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="property_map"></div>
<div id="pano"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That was very helpful and more importantly it works for me.